# How to find velocity at natural length when total mechanical energy is negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I'm attempting to answer the following questions:

'A particle of mass $1/2$ kg is attached to one end of a model spring which is hanging vertically from a fixed point A. The spring has stiffness $4 \, {\rm N \, m}^{−1}$ and a natural length of $1$ metre. The system is oscillating in a vertical line with the particle below A. Use the approximation that the magnitude of the acceleration due to gravity is $10 \, {\rm m \, s}^{−2}$.

(a) Find an expression for the total mechanical energy function for the
system, carefully defining your coordinate system and the datum for gravitational potential energy.

(b) When the particle is $2$ metres below $A$ it has speed $2 \, {\rm m \, s}^{−1}$. Use conservation of mechanical energy to establish whether the spring is ever in compression during the motion.(Hint: try to determine the speed of the particle when the spring has its
natural length.)'

for (a) $E= v^2/4 + 2(x-1)^2 - 5x$, where $1/2mv^2 = v^2/4$, $1/2k({\rm length - natural \, length})^2= 2(x-1)^2$, and mgx = -5x (with datum @ point A). Plugging in the values for $v$ and $x$ from part (b) produces a total energy of $-7$. When setting $E=-7$ and $x$ as natural length, $1$, to find $v$ at natural length, the equation becomes $v = \sqrt{-8}$, which is incorrect.

I have a feeling its something very obvious- apologies if it is, I am very new to this kind of physics/mathematics.

cheers

Comment: I would guess that natural length of the spring is the length when it is measured flat on the ground.  If that's right then with the parameters you have given I think the mass would hang naturally at 2.25m below A (if there were no oscillations).  If there are oscillations, how sure are you that the spring would make it all the way up to 1m below A?

Answer (score 1):

Your arithmetic is correct. As you say, a solution of $v=\sqrt{-8}$ when $x=1$ is unrealistic. This tells you that the particle never reaches $x=1$, so the spring is always longer than its natural length, and so never in compression.

An alternative approach is to find the two points at which $v=0$ by solving the quadratic equation

$2(x-1)^2 - 5x = -7$

These two points are the upper and lower extremes of the particle's motion. You will find that at both extreme points we have $x > 1$.